# Stream Optional List and return Optional List (JAVA 16)

Tags: lambda, java-stream, option-type, java-16

I have an Optional List

```
Optional<List<ProductType>> relatedProductTypes;
```

I want to populate this list, retrieving them from the Object Category:

```
public class Category {
    private String id;
    private String label;
    private Optional<List<ProductType>> productTypes;
}
```

If the list of productTypes is not empty, I want to return an Optional List with the elements, otherwise an empty Optional.
I want to do it with a lambda/stream, maybe using the MapMulti from Java 16.

This far I tried with

```
relatedProductTypes = category.getIdProductType()
                         .stream()
                         .filter(Optional::ifPresent) //this filter doesn't compile because I'm not in a static context and I don't know how to write it down
                         .map(idProductType ->
                                ProductType.builder()
                                 .id(idProductType.toString())
                                 .build())
                                 .collect(toList());
```

or with mapMulti()

```
relatedProductTypes = category.getIdProductType()
                          .stream()
                          .filter(Optional::ifPresent) //this filter doesn't compile because I'm not in a static context and I don't know how to write it down
                          .mapMulti((idProductType, something) ->
        something.accept(ProductType.builder()
                                    .id(idProductType.toString())
                                    .build()))
                          .collect(toList());
```

The problems are 1) I don't understand how to properly filter the values and 2) I always end up returning a List instead of an Optional<List>.
Do you have any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something obvious and I don't know what it is. Thank you so much!

Comment: First of all, you should simply not use a type like `Optional<List<ProductType>>`. What’s the semantical difference between an empty optional list and an non-empty optional containing an empty list? Then, your posted code snippets are not helpful. What is `category.getIdProductType()`? Is it the getter for `productTypes`, having a different name for some reason? How about just telling us what result type `category.getIdProductType()` has, instead of posting the (apparently) irrelevant parts of the `Category` class?

Comment: Just use a `List`, which can be initialized to an empty list.  Optional is not adding value here.

Comment: Thank you @Brian , I was just focused on Optionals that I misled myself. Thank you for your time!